# undefined scope object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html file and I want to show on it information from mongoDB.
I want to show all the messages that are in the mongoDB.
I build an html page that expect to information:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>List</h1>
    <br><br>

    <button ng-click="showAllButton()">Show All</button>
    <br> <br>

    <p>{{ tagline }}</p>

    <label for="messageName">Message Name:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%; float:center" ng-model="message.name"  name="message.name" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="text">Text:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.text" name="message.text" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="images">Images:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.images" name="message.images" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="template">Template:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.template" name="message.template" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="millisecToShow">Millisec To Show:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.millisecToShow" name="message.millisecToShow" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="timeFrame">Time Frame:</label><br>
    <label for="TimeStart">Start Time:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.startDateTime" name="message.startDateTime" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="DateStart">End Time:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.endDateTime" name="message.endDateTime" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="days">Days:</label><br>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.days" name="message.days" readonly/>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="screenId">Screen ID:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:50%" ng-model="message.screenId" name="message.screenId" readonly/>
    <br><br>

    <button ng-click="nextMsg()">Next</button>
    <button ng-click="previousMsg()">previous</button>
    <br><br>

</div>
```

and I have that controller to do it:

```
angular.module('ListCtrl', []).controller('ListController', function($scope, superService) {

var index = 0;

    $scope.showAllButton = function() {
        superService.list().then(function (result) {

            if ((result != "false") && (result != undefined)) {
                index = 0;

                $scope.tagline = result;
                $scope.message.name = result[index].messageName;
                $scope.message.text = result[index].text;
                $scope.message.images = result[index].images;
                $scope.message.template = result[index].template;
                $scope.message.millisecToShow = result[index].millisecToShow;
                $scope.message.startDateTime = result[index].timeFrame[0].date.start + ". Time: " + result[0].timeFrame[0].time.start.hour + ":" + result[0].timeFrame[0].time.start.minutes;
                $scope.message.endDateTime = result[index].timeFrame[0].date.end + ". Time: " + result[0].timeFrame[0].time.end.hour + ":" + result[0].timeFrame[0].time.end.minutes;;
                $scope.message.days = result[index].timeFrame[0].days;
                $scope.message.screenId = result[index].screenId;
            }
            else {
                $scope.tagline = 'No messages';
            }
            return result.data;
        });
    };
```

The information that I get from the DB is fine.
but that informtion don't shown in the textboxs, the error is: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined". $scope.message is undefined.
someone can please tell me why and how I fix this?
thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.message` is undefined so you have to define it. e.g.:

```
$scope.message = {};
$scope.message.name = result[index].messageName;
...
```